# Related Posts function not working

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, query, get-posts

I have set up this function which in theory should display 2 Related Posts to some Post, but it makes my site go blank.

```
<?php
$orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>2, // Number of related posts to display.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>

    <li class="full entry animate-box ll-article" style="background-image: url('<?php set_featured_image_bg(); ?>');" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="entry-desc">
            <div class="border-police">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

<? }
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate answer will be in your server logs, I'm afraid. (You can also turn on debugging in wp-config - sometimes that helps too)

But I did notice a few things that hopefully can help you track the issue:

```
<?php
// You should not require the $orig_post variable...
global $post;
// Get the tag ids directly:
$tag_ids = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
if (!empty($tag_ids)) {
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>2, // Number of related posts to display.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post();
// **** What is the "set_featured_image_bg" function? Is it defined?
?>

    <li class="full entry animate-box ll-article" style="background-image: url('<?php set_featured_image_bg(); ?>');" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="entry-desc">
            <div class="border-police">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

<? }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // use this instead of "wp_reset_query", and right after you end your while loop...
}
?>
```

Good luck!